# Get Link to this cell in Google sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink, array-formulas

How can I get a link to cell in sheets with a formula or appscript? I have a column A with 200 rows and want to get the links of all cells populated in column B

Comment: Web link or address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the first cell (A1) and copy the link to that cell. Then use that link like the example below and drag this down.

> =CONCATENATE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/a1a1a1a1a1a1/edit#gid=111111&range=A",ROW()))

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B:B="",,HYPERLINK("#gid=1734824104&range=B"&ROW(B:B), B:B)))
```

[image: 0]

where gid number can be found here:

[image]